# how to replace bool false to true flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in the case here I want to change the boolean value false to true by clicking Inkwel 1x in the flutter programming language. Where the key that I will change is in the array list for the menu. So when the menu is clicked, the key starts with false, then it will change to true. following my code. what I will change is the favorite key[image]

This array data :

```
List<menuData> _menuServiceList = [];



    @override
  void initState() {
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 1, name: 'menu 1', image: 'assets/icon/balancesheet.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 2, name: 'menu 2', image: 'assets/icon/card.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 3, name: 'menu 3', image: 'assets/icon/decrease.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 5, name: 'menu 4', image: 'assets/icon/growth.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 5, name: 'menu 5', image: 'assets/icon/growth.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 6, name: 'menu 6', image: 'assets/icon/officesupplies.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 7, name: 'menu 7', image: 'assets/icon/piechart.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 8, name: 'menu 8', image: 'assets/icon/sharemoney.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 9, name: 'menu 9', image: 'assets/icon/speechbubble.png', favorit: false
    ));
    _menuServiceList.add(new menuData(
        id: 10, name: 'menu 10', image: 'assets/icon/grid.png', favorit: true
    ));

    super.initState();
  }
```

this code clicked button :

```
   child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              if (menuData.favorit == false){
                print("klik false");
                
              }else{
                print("klik true");
              }
            });
          },
          child:  HeaderItem(
            images: menuData.image,
            title: menuData.name,
            textcolor: Colors.grey[600],
          ) ,
        )
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you really want to do ?

Comment: change the value of the favorite key from false to true, and vice versa @Shubhamhackz

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please make sure `menuData.favorit` is mutable. then just update the flag accordingly

```
child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
               menuData.favorit = !menuData.favorit;
            });
          },
          child:  HeaderItem(
            images: menuData.image,
            title: menuData.name,
            textcolor: Colors.grey[600],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: for boolean values, I think I can update the values. from false to true. can you explain specifically?

Comment: this exclamation mark (!) is called negation for values. If menuData.favroite is false then after setState it will be true, or If menuData.favroite is true then after setState it will be false. You can change the bool value as much as you can as long as it is mutable. Please read programming fundamtals before jumping writing code, otherwise you will have huge problem in the future

Comment: I made the list so I can't change the value? @Jasurbek